# Ordering posts by custom taxonomy in admin area

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, admin, sort

**EDIT**

@kaiser - this question is slightly different to the answer you posted in that I am talking about sorting by clicking the column title rather than adding a dropdown to filter by taxonomy term (which you'll see I've already done in the screenshot).

Like Otto says in the answer Milo linked to: 'it is not possible to order by taxonomy, because from a certain type of standpoint, that doesn't actually make much sense...the point of having a taxonomy on posts would really be to have terms in that taxonomy that are shared between posts'.

I see his point, as you can have multiple terms attached to a post, sorting by them is a bit pointless. I've decided to scrap the idea, so feel free to delete this post if it's of no use. Thanks.

**ENDEDIT**

Been scouring the net for the solution to this, but not finding the specific answer to my issue. I've registered a custom post type and a couple of custom taxonomies, but I'm trying to  allow admins to *sort* posts by a taxonomy, just like you can with the Date column - see screenshot here:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do that? Here's how I'm registering the custom post type if it's of any use:

```
Class OSUFestivals
    {
        public static function init()
        {
            add_action( "init", array( __CLASS__, "register_directory_cpt" ) );
            add_action( "init", array( __CLASS__, "register_workshop_type_taxonomy" ) );
            add_action( "init", array( __CLASS__, "register_day_taxonomy" ) );
        }

        public static function register_directory_cpt()
        {
            $labels = array(
                'name'               => 'Festival Items',
                'singular_name'      => 'Festival Item',
                'menu_name'          => 'Festival',
                'name_admin_bar'     => 'Festival Item',
                'add_new'            => 'Add New Item',
                'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Item',
                'new_item'           => 'New Item',
                'edit_item'          => 'Edit Item',
                'view_item'          => 'View Item',
                'all_items'          => 'All Items',
                'search_items'       => 'Search Items',
                'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Items:',
                'not_found'          => 'No Items found.',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Items found in Trash.',
            );
            $args = array(
                'labels'        => $labels,
                'public'        => true,
                'hierarchical'  => false,
                'has_archive'   => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'excerpt', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
                'rewrite'       => array(
                    'with_front'    => false,
                    'slug'          => 'festival-Items'
                )
            );

            register_post_type( 'lkfestival', $args );
        }

        public static function register_workshop_type_taxonomy()
        {
            $labels = array(
                'name'                      => 'Workshop types',
                'singular_name'             => 'Workshop type',
                'search_items'              => 'Search workshop types',
                'all_items'                 => 'All workshop types',
                'parent_item'               => 'Parent workshop type',
                'edit_item'                 => 'Edit workshop type',
                'update_item'               => 'Update workshop type',
                'add_new_item'              => 'Add new workshop type',
                'new_item_name'             => 'New workshop type',
                'choose_from_most_used'     => 'Choose from most used workshop types'
            );

            $args = array(
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'labels'            => $labels,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'event-type' ),
                'capabilities'      => array (
                    /* Only let Andrea assign workshop types */
                    'manage_terms'  => 'manage_options', // by default only admin
                    'edit_terms'    => 'manage_options',
                    'delete_terms'  => 'manage_options',
                    'assign_terms'  => 'edit_posts'  // means administrator', 'editor', 'author', 'contributor'
                )
            );

            register_taxonomy( 'lktypes', 'lkfestival', $args );
        }

        public static function register_day_taxonomy()
        {
            $labels = array(
                'name'                      => 'Festival days',
                'singular_name'             => 'Festival day',
                'search_items'              => 'Search festival days',
                'all_items'                 => 'All festival days',
                'parent_item'               => 'Parent festival day',
                'edit_item'                 => 'Edit festival day',
                'update_item'               => 'Update festival day',
                'add_new_item'              => 'Add new festival day',
                'new_item_name'             => 'New festival day',
                'choose_from_most_used'     => 'Choose from most used festival days'
            );

            $args = array(
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'labels'            => $labels,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'day' ),
                'capabilities'      => array (
                    /* Only let Andrea assign festival days */
                    'manage_terms'  => 'manage_options', // by default only admin
                    'edit_terms'    => 'manage_options',
                    'delete_terms'  => 'manage_options',
                    'assign_terms'  => 'edit_posts'  // means administrator', 'editor', 'author', 'contributor'
                )
            );

            register_taxonomy( 'lkdays', 'lkfestival', $args );
        }

    }

    // Load Class
    OSUFestivals::init();
```

I thought the 'sort' parameter in `register_taxonomy()` would allow sorting, but it looks like that's related to the order in which terms are added to objects.

Comment: Sorting by taxonomy term is not something the API can do natively, see [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/14306/4771).

Comment: I see, that's a tricky one then. Thank you for that link, I'll have to think about whether to get around this issue then or scrap the idea...

Comment: Q: [Custom Table Column Sortable by Taxonomy Query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109955/custom-table-column-sortable-by-taxonomy-query) A: [Adding Custom Sortable WordPress Admin Table Columns by Taxonomy Terms](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/119584/9579)

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do to sort my custom post type by custom taxonomy in the admin.  I have a custom post type called plugin_filter and a custom taxonomy assigned to it called filter_group.  I add the following filter to my plugin to make the field sortable.

```
add_filter("manage_edit-plugin_filter_sortable_columns", 'plugin_filter_sort');
function plugin_filter_sort($columns) {
   $custom = array(
       'taxonomy-filter_group' => 'taxonomy-filter_group'
   );
   return wp_parse_args($custom, $columns);
}
```